# Is there a way to test against a SQL Server databse in a build pipeline?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

The company I work for has some functional tests they want to run as part of the normal build process that require a SQL Server database to test against.

So far the only way I've found to try to do this in the build pipeline is to stand up a SQL Server Express Docker container, but the only one I've found is 6GB and eats up way too much time. Is there a trick I'm not aware of to do this? It seems like you can test against Azure SQL databases if you have an Azure subscription but only in a release pipeline, which is not ideal.

For reference we are using the MS hosted VS2017 agents. I've had the conversation with the man in charge about seeing if we can modify the tests to either not need a DB at all but let's just say we haven't seen eye to eye. :)

Any help appreciated, but mostly shooting in the dark.

Comment: SQL for Linux container is only about 500MB

Comment: Aware of that, trying to avoid needing to spin up a second agent just to run the Docker container and the agent for the rest of the pipeline the VS2017 agent, which the Linux container isn't compatible with, unless there is something I've missed.